# Ignore certain words (http address) in textspeech

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

Is it possible to have text2speech ignore certain words when it's speaking? For example, instead of reading an "http" address, just skip it.

I am developing a program that help users learn another language. For example, "Hola = Hello". Is it possible for the text2speech to ignore hello and just say Hola?

If not that, is it possible to have them both spoken but in their own languages: Spanish and then in English.

The vocab word is on one editText. Because of spacing, I am confined to using one editText. However, if there's a suggestion, please do share.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is your requirement, still, you can set the language for the engine.
Like:

```
TextToSpeech tts=new TextToSpeech(this,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Also, instead of asking the `tts` to skip some, why don't you skip those from the input text? I think that's a better way.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that's not exactly what I was asking. It's seemed from the lack of replies, it can't be done. I found a work around thought. :-)

Answer (score 0):

After many years, I realized I never give an answer to my question. Since nobody else answered, I'm assuming it's very beginner, and everybody seemed to know how to do it.

Well, for those who want to know. I thought I'll share what I figured out. If there are words, I don't want my text2speech to not say, I simply delete/replace it before processing it in text2speech engine.

I use string search and/ split to remove unwanted symbols.